# Having trouble encrypting text using AES-128-CBC

Tags: php, encryption, opayo

Here's the brief from the payment gateway (Elavon):

> The string must be encrypted using AES (block size 128-bit) in CBC mode with PKCS#5 padding. Use the provided password as both the key and initialisation vector and encode the result in hex (making sure the letters are in upper case).
> Prepend the ‘@’ sign to the beginning of the encoded result.

Here's my code:

```
    function encryptAesTest($string, $key)
        {
            $cipher = "aes-128-cbc";
            $crypt = openssl_encrypt($string, $cipher, $key, 0, $key);
            return "@" . strtoupper(bin2hex($crypt));
        }
```

The question is, does this code satisfy the brief from the payment gateway ?

I am attempting to convert from mcrypt_encrypt -> openssl_encrypt

My PHP version is 8.2.13

I *think* I might be going wrong with PKCS#5 padding as I understand that openssl_encrypt uses PKCS#7 padding

The error message from Elavon (SagePay) is unhelpful:

> 5080 : Form transaction registration failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: PHP/OpenSSL Base64 encodes by default. To prevent this, the `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` flag must be set in the fourth parameter of `openssl_encrypt()`. This is probably the cause for your problem.

Comment: Padding shouldn't be a problem. Some libraries use the term PKCS#5 padding for PKCS#7 padding for historical reasons (for more details see e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9044)).

Comment: If the password is truly a password and thus has limited entropy, using the password as both the key and IV makes rainbow table-based attacks possible.

Comment: Just a note: the payment gateway is asking for a "block size 128-bit" (that AES does have) but nothing about the encryption strength (= length of the encryption key). My recommendation is to use AES-256 (key length 32 bytes) instead of AES-128 (key length 16 bytes).

Comment: Problem is the key and the IV are predetermined and they are both 16 bytes...

Comment: @MichaelFehr - The specification implies AES-128: The password is to be used as key and IV. Since the IV for AES has 16 bytes, this conversely means that the key also has 16 bytes, i.e. AES-128.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document [*Sage Pay Form Integration and Protocol Guidelines 3.00*](https://www.elavon.co.uk/content/dam/elavon/en-gb/v2/documents/resource-center/opayo/my-opayo---sagepay/troubleshooting/FORM_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_270815.pdf) (see sec. *A1.2 Example Crypt Field*, p. 38) contains test data (in sec. *A1.1 The Crypt field* you will also find the specification that corresponds to yours):

```
plaintext:   VendorTxCode=TxCode-1310917599-223087284&Amount=36.95&Currency=GBP&Description=description&CustomerName=Fname Surname&CustomerEMail=customer@example.com&BillingSurname=Surname&BillingFirstnames=Fname&BillingAddress1=BillAddress Line 1&BillingCity=BillCity&BillingPostCode=W1A 1BL&BillingCountry=GB&BillingPhone=447933000000&DeliveryFirstnames=Fname&DeliverySurname=Surname&DeliveryAddress1=BillAddress Line 1&DeliveryCity=BillCity&DeliveryPostCode=W1A 1BL&DeliveryCountry=GB&DeliveryPhone=447933000000&SuccessURL=https://example.com/success&FailureURL=https://example.com/failure
password:    55a51621a6648525
ciphertext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
```

If in the posted code the default Base64 encoding in [`openssl_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) is disabled with [`OPENSSL_RAW_DATA`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.constants.other.php), the code works. Using the above password and plaintext results in the expected ciphertext!

Fixed PHP code:

```php
<?php
$user_string = "VendorTxCode=TxCode-1310917599-223087284&Amount=36.95&Currency=GBP&Description=description&CustomerName=Fname Surname&CustomerEMail=customer@example.com&BillingSurname=Surname&BillingFirstnames=Fname&BillingAddress1=BillAddress Line 1&BillingCity=BillCity&BillingPostCode=W1A 1BL&BillingCountry=GB&BillingPhone=447933000000&DeliveryFirstnames=Fname&DeliverySurname=Surname&DeliveryAddress1=BillAddress Line 1&DeliveryCity=BillCity&DeliveryPostCode=W1A 1BL&DeliveryCountry=GB&DeliveryPhone=447933000000&SuccessURL=https://example.com/success&FailureURL=https://example.com/failure";
$key = '55a51621a6648525';
$iv = '55a51621a6648525';
function encryptAesTest($string, $key)
{
    $cipher = "aes-128-cbc";
    $crypt = openssl_encrypt($string, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $key); // Fix: disable Base64 encoding 
    return "@" . strtoupper(bin2hex($crypt));
}
print(encryptAesTest($user_string, $key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
?>
```

---

*Security:* The protocol has the following vulnerabilities:
The key seems to be a hex encoded value, which limits the range of values per key byte from 256 to 16 (so effectively only an 8 byte key is used instead of a 16 byte key), which is a serious vulnerability.
In addition, the use of the key as IV is a vulnerability since this results in the reuse of key/IV pairs.

Comment: Thanks Topaco - I arrived at the same conclusions and it turns out that there were some problems with my $string text as well - all sorted now :) Thanks !